# Why this PreparedStaement throws a mysql error?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am doing an insertion in a mysql database through a jdbc connection, which connects perfectly, that if when I do the PreparedStatement, Tomcat throws me a sql error that says the following:

`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?)' at line 1`

The question is that when I do the query through a statement, it performs the query without any problem, which makes me suspect that the error is actually in the PreparedSatement. Here I leave the code.

```
@Override
public void save(Planet planet) throws SQLException {
    String namePlanet = planet.getName();
    float massPlanet = planet.getMass();
    boolean habitablePlanet = planet.isHabitable();
    sql = "INSERT INTO planeta (nom,massa,habitable) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, namePlanet);
    preparedStatement.setFloat(2, massPlanet);
    preparedStatement.setBoolean(3, habitablePlanet);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
}
```

I will also leave the code with the preparedstatement, so you can see that this does work.

```
@Override
public void save(Planet planet) throws SQLException {
    String namePlanet = planet.getName();
    float massPlanet = planet.getMass();
    boolean habitablePlanet = planet.isHabitable();
    sql = "insert into planeta(nom,massa,habitable) value('" + namePlanet + "'," + massPlanet + "," + habitablePlanet + ")";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

}
```

Please be patient with me, I'm a student and thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to call executeUpdate() without parameter. The second excample is not a prepared statement.

Comment: Ok thx a lot, now it works!!! Thx again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Jens told in the comments i have to call `executeUpdate()` without parameters.

Thx again @Jens!!

Thats the correct code:

```
@Override
public void save(Planet planet) throws SQLException {
    String namePlanet = planet.getName();
    float massPlanet = planet.getMass();
    boolean habitablePlanet = planet.isHabitable();
    sql = "INSERT INTO planeta (nom,massa,habitable) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, namePlanet);
    preparedStatement.setFloat(2, massPlanet);
    preparedStatement.setBoolean(3, habitablePlanet);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); // <--- Here was the error!!
```

}